# The minimum constant that increases the number sequence, which has fixed start number and end number.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

This is the original problem:

*Suppose there is a sequence of 20 cells, the first cell contains number 1 and the last cell contains 50. We would like to fill all cells with integer numbers in such a way that numbers in the neighbouring cells differ by at most k. For which minimal k this is possible?*

To my understanding, I figure we can just find the available k to increase from 1 and the number that after the addition and so on to the final number 50.

So I wrote a program to find this k.

I assume the k is 2, and the result is following:

```
let nums = [];
let k = 2;

for (let i = 1; nums.length < 20; i += k) {
    nums.push(i);
}

console.log(nums);
// [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39]
```

Since the last number is way smaller than 50, then I tried k = 3, here’s what I got:

```
let nums = [];
let k = 3;

for (let i = 1; nums.length < 20; i += k) {
    nums.push(i);
}

console.log(nums);
// [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49, 52, 55, 58]
```

It’s obvious that when k = 3, the last number has outnumbered than 50… so it’s not 3.

Then I tried the number within the range 2 to 3, and I got 2.5 is the closest one to make the whole sequence reach at 50.

But the question asks for an integer… so 2.5 is incorrect…

But 2 is incorrect either...

Did I comprehend the question in a wrong way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question states

> We would like to fill all cells with integer numbers in such a way that numbers in the neighbouring cells differ by at *most* k.

I emphasized "most" to indicate the actual difference between cells can be $0$ up to $k$, inclusive. However, to determine the smallest possible $k$, you will only want to increase values instead of not changing them or decreasing them. In particular, you'll want to check what the minimum value of $k$ is such that, using this value for each difference, you'll get to at least $50$.

As you've shown, this cannot work for $k = 2$ since the highest possible value of $39$, which is less than $50$. However, for $k = 3$, you found using that for each difference gets you to $58$. Thus, you can reduce the difference in some of the cells so the maximum value reached would be $50$, for example by reducing the difference by $1$ between any $8$ pairs of cells.

This shows the requested answer is $k = 3$.

Comment: Oh my god, you are so right! So my misunderstand what the question ask, right? It's not looking for a constant but a dynamic value and the k is the upper bound. Also it's not required that each number between 1 to 50 have to increment the same number, right? God, this makes so much sense now!!! Thank you!

Comment: @BenjaminLi You're welcome, and your interpretation as stated above is correct.